# Why does pattern matching Map with Tuple inside Stream/Enum module in Elixir Works?

Tags: elixir

If I have understood correctly, **tuples** in elixir are represented with `{}` while **Maps** are represented as a key:value pair with `%{key: value}`.

In the following code, the `Stream.filter` and `Enum.map` accepts `entries` as input, which is a `Map` and iterates over it.

But the `lambda` function inside them is doing a pattern matching on `{_, entry}` which is a `tuple`. How come this works?

```elixir
defmodule TodoList do
   defstruct auto_id: 1, entries: %{}

   def new(), do: %TodoList{}

  def add_entry(todo_list, entry) do
    entry = Map.put(entry, :id, todo_list.auto_id)
    new_entries = Map.put(
      todo_list.entries,
      todo_list.auto_id,
      entry)

    %TodoList{todo_list |
      entries: new_entries,
      auto_id: todo_list.auto_id + 1
    }
  end

  def entries(todo_list, date) do
    todo_list.entries
    |> Stream.filter(fn {_, entry} -> entry.date == date end)
    |> Enum.map(fn {_, entry} -> entry end)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterations in *Elixir* are possible by the implementation of [`Enumerable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enumerable.html?) protocol. That means, anything, implementing `Enumerable` can be iterated using methods from `Enum` and `String` modules.

The implementation of this protocol *for* `Map` [delegates](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ee758f987b7e240754bf386b903b92d38fb02233/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L3692) to `Enumerable.List.reduce/3`, passing the map converted to a list with [`:maps.to_list/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#to_list-1).

The latter transforms the map to a list in the form `[{k1, v1}, {k2, v2}, ...]`.

```elixir
iex|1 ▶ :maps.to_list(%{k1: :v1, k2: :v2})
#⇒ [k1: :v1, k2: :v2] # essentially the list of tuples
iex|2 ▶ [k1: :v1, k2: :v2] == [{:k1, :v1}, {:k2, :v2}]
#⇒ true
```

These tuples are being emitted in `Enum.map` in your example.

Comment: Wow. That's a nice explanation. Thanks for helping me out. I am yet to read about Protocols in Elixir. I am wondering why this implicit conversion takes place!

Because I assumed to pattern match with Map instead of Tuple and was confused about this implementation.

Comment: Welcome. [Here is the best place](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html) to start reading about protocols.